# EPiServer - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: key, duplicates, episerver

I'm getting lots of the following errors in EPiServer 7.5:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value,     Boolean add) +10925834
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +10
   EPiServer.Core.DynamicPropertyBag.Add(DynamicProperty property) +260
   EPiServer.Core.DynamicPropertyLookup.InternalAdd(DynamicProperty dynamicProperty) +199
   EPiServer.Core.DynamicPropertyLookup..ctor(DynamicPropertyCollection properties) +256
   EPiServer.Core.DynamicPropertyCache.get_DynamicPropertyFinder() +230
   EPiServer.Core.PropertyGetHandler.DefaultPropertyHandler(String name, PropertyDataCollection properties) +193
   EPiServer.Core.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String name) +80
```

...does anyone know where I can find these duplicate keys in the database and remove them, or is there a better way to fix this?

thanks

Comment: Something is wrong. Are you getting the error on startup or on random requests?

Answer (score 0):

Never found a solution to this. Had to rollback the database to before the issue happened.

Comment: I would guess it comes from an error in model syncing. For example, copying/pasting a content type which has a GUID explicitly set can cause problems. This could be something similar to that.